# How to change Ribbon colors on Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, ribbon, delphi-10.2-tokyo

We are using [RibbonFramework](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/RibbonFramework) which is just Delphi wrapper for the Windows Ribbon Framework. Everything worked fine until we started upgrading to Windows 10, where the color settings stopped working.

We use the `BackgroundColor` property, which eventually sets [UI_PKEY_GlobalBackgroundColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/windowsribbon-reference-properties-uipkey-globalbackgroundcolor) to change background color. Unfortunately, it works only partially, it never sets the correct color, but a gray tint with a hint of the selected color. The fact that in this case the green instead of purple is set is just a small detail.

I can't find where the problem might be whether the Windows 10 color settings is not working or it is no longer supported, or I'm doing something wrong.

Below you can see how the same application [TextPad demo](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/RibbonFramework/tree/master/Samples/High%20Level/06%20Text%20Pad) looks like on different versions of Windows, all except Windows 10 are working properly. I tested it on dozens of different computers with different settings and the result was always the same.

**Windows 7 (Windows Server 2008)**

[image]

**Windows 8 (Windows Server 2012)**

[image]

**Windows 10 - build 17763**

[image]

**With all possible colors set to pure red**

[image]

Comment: I don't have a Windows 10 machine available right now, but I just came to think about the Windows theme setting. Do you have the same (or similar) settings?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes, it's globally set up for all machines and it doesn't seem to have any effect. In the Ribbon Designer in the Preview mode on the Colorize page you can set any color and on Win 10 it always sets the shade of gray, only the color of the Application menu is changing and even the wrong one.

Comment: According to documentation on Windows 10 ribbon controls are using `Hue, Saturation, Brightness (HSB) color model` and not `RGB color model`. Based on the fact that you get wrong color I asume that your application is still using `RGB based color model` especially since all other Delphi controls relly on `RGB color model`. So I suggest you check [Convert RGB to HSB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/ribbon-color#convert-rgb-to-hsb)

Comment: @SilverWarior I'm well aware of this, bad color conversion is probably the reason why I see green instead of purple, but it still doesn't explain why it's not possible to change the background color. All Ribbon colors set to pure red https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdkN1.png

Comment: Interesting - what does it look like without setting any color? In MS Paint for example, it looks precisely like your Win10 screenshot, in exception of the green. Mine is blue. My guess is color support has been discontinued.

Comment: @JerryDodge Without any color it looks like you said, just gray with a blue menu. I also thought that the support has been discontinued, but if that's true, I'd expect to find mention of it somewhere. All the resources I found suggest that nothing has changed and it should still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the system that appeared in the Windows 10 v.1809 (October 2018 Update). So far, there seems to be nothing to do about it and no way around it until they fix it themselves.

It has already been reported on their [Gtihub for MicrosoftDocs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/feedback/issues/2738) and also on the [Windows Desktop Ribbon Developement](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/78ea4255-78b9-4602-a7c1-180c833985d9/changing-windows-ribbon-background-color-does-not-seem-to-work-anymore-in-windows-10-v1809-and?forum=windowsribbondevelopment) forum.